# SmartGWT: Programmatically set edit value in list grid to null for numeric field

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt

I need to set edit value in list grid from existing value to null in numeric field. Edits come from external component and must be reflected on the grid. Filed is not required so it can have null value.
I was trying the following:

1) throws an exception

```
Integer nullValue = null;
listGrid.setEditValue(rowNum, fieldName, nullValue);
```

2) look like this is working the same as clearEditValue(rowNum, "fieldName")

```
HashMap map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("fieldName", null);
listGrid.setEditValues(rowNum, map);
```

I'm using SmartGWT 6.0p

Comment: what happened after you tried the above two solutions? were there any warning or error message?

Comment: With the first solution I'm getting NPE from the SmartGWT framework. With the second nothing is happening (original value is still visible in the cell)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution. Regardless of filed type I can cast null to String
In this case SmartGWT is not throwing any exception and edit value is set to null

```
listGrid.setEditValue(rowNum, fieldName (String)null);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm able to set a cell of a `Integer` field to `null` in a `ListGrid` with the following code

```
public void setCellValue(int rowNum, String nameOfField, ListGrid listgrid) {
   ListGridRecord row = listgrid.getRecord(rowNum);
   Integer intNull = null;
   row.setAttribute(nameOfField, intNull);
   listgrid.updateData(row);
}
```

After setCellValue was called, the corresponding cell correctly changed to blank.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but during invocation of updateData data is send to server. I need to show changes before user decide to press save button